# What is the differences between Object AXES and Edit Mode AXES

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, axis

What is the differences between Object AXES and Edit Mode AXES
[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSqAs.png)[image: example][image: video screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In object mode you can read the orientation of the whole Armature object (which is the orientation of its origin, and can also be in a location in which there is no bone), in edit mode you can read every single orientation of every single bone of the armature.

The orientation of every bone is displayed at the tip of the bone, but I think is more intuitive to think at it located at the root of the bone, where the rotations will happen.

Comment: This leads me to a new question but I do not know if it is enough to merit a new question so I will do it in the comment and I will come up with the original question with these answers, when you have to align the axes of the bones, with CTRL + N which alignment you should correct. ? mode object or mode edition?

Comment: I can't think of a situation in which it's useful to have the axis in object mode not aligned with the world coordinates. In edit mode we generally try to align the more useful rotations of every bone with a single axis, and there is the general convention of aligning the "main" rotation with the X axis. This kind of choices lead to a better uderstanding of the animation, expecially when it comes to add constraints and use the graph editor to edit the rotations.

Comment: then to align the bones I must be in edit mode, which would allow me to correctly align the axes for optimal functioning

Comment: I had these doubts because I saw several videos but one in particular I think confusion about it, because at one point his bones are misaligned, then aligns them and the Z axes remain as they should be, but if I do the same thing, I do not aligns the Z axis correctly, and I do not know if I'm doing it wrong or I did not understand or something is not right in the video

Comment: Yes, you should do this kind of thing in edit mode. Which is the video?

Comment: the videos ar in spanis [1](https://youtu.be/UX7oou8gSFs),  [2](https://youtu.be/OywxG9gOCdk),  [3](https://youtu.be/zoAyopks5MY),  [4](https://youtu.be/OdJdvgEkduU)

Comment: I have put a screenshot of the video
he changes the value of the roll to 0, and his axes are aligned correctly but if I do the same do not remain so, com you can see in my image the axis is wrong aligned I tried making a single armor with united guesses and an armor with bones separated